# Rails 3: how to get the input from a check_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I'm quite new to ruby on rails... My problem is to get the output from a checkbox. If the 
checkbox is `false`, I want to show every concert, but I always get the else condition...
How is it possible to get `@concerts = Concert.find(:all, :order => "day")` as standard output and if the check_box is checked get the else condition?

```
#index.html.erb
check_box('dm', false, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")


# controller.rb
def index
  if params[:dm] == '0'
    @concerts = Concert.find(:all, :order => "day")
  else
    @concerts = Concert.find(:all, :order => "day", :conditions => {:bool => false})
end
```

## development.log

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-14 13:21:39 +0200
Processing by ConcertsController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mConcert Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `concerts`.* FROM `concerts` WHERE `concerts`.`bool` = 0 ORDER BY day[0m
  [1m[35mConcert Load (15.6ms)[0m  SELECT `concerts`.* FROM `concerts` ORDER BY lineup
  [1m[36mConcert Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT DISTINCT day FROM `concerts` ORDER BY day[0m
  [1m[35mConcert Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT DISTINCT club_id FROM `concerts` 
...
Rendered concerts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (78.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 78.0ms | ActiveRecord: 15.6ms)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def index
  if params[:dm] == '0'
    @concerts = Concert.find(:all, :order => "day")
  else
    @concerts = Concert.find(:all, :order => "day", :conditions => {:bool => false})
end
```

Checkbox values received by controller are either 0 or 1 in string form. Also, it should be `params[:dm]`.

Comment: Update your question with log messages from `development.log` for a specific request.

Comment: just added the development.log. This is the output, when the application is loaded. When I check the checkbox, nothing is added to the log-file...

Comment: I wanted you to add log corresponding to POST request when you submit the form.

Comment: mhhh, never got anything about POST in the log file... Perhaps this is the problem?